# How to delete an item in Pycairo

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I'm trying to make a simple drawing program. I can draw a rectangle based on the mouse coordinates , but I don't know how to delete old elements so that I have the same behavior as in the second video.How can I implement the behavior from the second video (Where the rectangle is on a white background)?
Now here's how: https://youtu.be/a7MWjOXk84Y
Correct behavior : https://youtu.be/WFdPb2vixQg

Comment: Hi, providing a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help better explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a white background, I would propose to draw a white background. `cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1); cairo_paint(cr);` should do the job (this fills everything with white).

Your video shows a rectangle that is "not actually drawn" until the mouse is released (as in: the rectangle can still be removed later). For this, you need to keep around the image data without the rectangle so that you can get rid of the rectangle. Cairo provides no built-in way to do so.

Comment: Please tell me what methods i can use to do this

Comment: Have two surfaces. The first one has all the stuff that should be permanent. The second one is a copy of the first one to which you add a rectangle. To remove that rectangle again, you just copy again from the first surface.